# Get each item within a capturing group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If you have a string like this:

`[hello world] this is [the   best .Home] is nice place.`

How do you extract each word(separated by space) within brackets[] only.
Right now I have this working https://regex101.com/r/Tgokeq/2

**Which returns**:

hello world

the   best .Home

**But I want:**

hello

world

the

best

.Home

PS: I know I could just do string split in a foreach but I don't want that I want it in the regex itself, just like this which gets every word, except I want  words within the brackets [ ] only.
https://regex101.com/r/eweRWj/2

Comment: I already know I can do that as you can see in the last paragraph of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Pattern `([^\[\] ]+)(?=[^\[\]]*\])` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tgokeq/4)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^\[\] ]      # Character not in [\[\] ] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  [^\[\]]       # Character not in [\[\]] Character Class
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  \]            # "]"
)               # End of Look-Ahead
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what i wanted, and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is not possible in python right? Because python believes you only have one capturing group.

Comment: @TheChetan, I don't know about python, but you could also check the whole match without capturing groups

Answer (score 0):

This pattern may not seems as elegant since it does not match individual words separately. The full solution takes advantage of .Net regex library to get individual words. However, it avoids excessive backtracking of alpha bravo's solution.  The importance of that will largely depend on how many lines you search and/or if you are matching large chunks of text or only individual lines at a time.

This approach also lets you identify exactly how many bracket pairs and which words were captured in each pair.  A simple pattern-only solution will just get you the matched words without context.

The pattern:

```
\[\s*((?<word>[^[\]\s]+)\s*)+]
```

Then some brief code demonstrating how to get captured words via the .Net regex object model:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[\s*((?<word>[^[\]\s]+)\s*)+]");
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(searchText);
foreach(Match m in matches) {
    foreach(Capture c in m.Groups["word"].Captures) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    }
}
```

Breakdown of pattern:

```
\[              # Opening bracket
  \s*           # Optional white space
  (             # Group for word delimited by space
    (?<word>    # Named capture group
      [^[\]\s]  # Negative character class: no brackets, no white space
      +         # one or more greedy
    )           # End named capture group
    \s*         # Match white space after word
  )             # End of word+space grouping
  +             # Match multiple occurrences of word+space
]               # Literal closing bracket (no need to escape outside character class)
```

The above will match line feeds between the brackets.  If you don't want that then use

```
\[\ *((?<word>[^[\]\s]+)\ *)+]
```